# CONNECT BY vs recursive query

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my table,

```
CREATE TABLE "FILES" 
   (    
     "DISKELEMENTID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "FILENAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
      "PARENTDISKELEMENTID" NUMBER, 
       CONSTRAINT "FILES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DISKELEMENTID")
   )
```

and the data :

```
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (1,'C:',null);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (2,'D:',null);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (3,'C:\OperatingSystem',1);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (4,'C:\Temp',1);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (5,'D:\Video',2);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (6,'D:\Music',2);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (7,'C:\OperatingSystem\file01.txt',3);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (8,'C:\OperatingSystem\file02.txt',3);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (9,'D:\Video\video01.avi',5);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (10,'D:\Video\video01.avi',5);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (11,'D:\Video\Temp',5);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (12,'D:\Video\Temp\file-d-temp01.txt',11);
Insert into FILES (DISKELEMENTID,FILENAME,PARENTDISKELEMENTID) values (13,'D:\Video\Temp\file-d-temp02.txt',11);
```

I am want an explanation / double check if my code is the same : same query implemented with CONNECT by and same query implemented with recursive query.
Even if the data returned is the same, i would like a check / explanation why it is the same.

Query with CONNECT BY :

```
SELECT Files.DiskElementId,
   prior FileName as Parent,
  CONNECT_BY_ROOT FileName as TopParent,
  Files.FileName FROM Files 
  START WITH ParentDiskElementID is NULL
  connect by prior DiskElementID = ParentDiskElementID 
  ORDER BY DiskElementId
```

and query with recursive query:

```
with q(DiskElementId, Parent,TopParent,FileName) as
(
  SELECT 
      DiskElementId, 
      null as Parent, 
      FileName as TopParent,
      FileName
    FROM Files WHERE parentdiskelementid is null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
      Files.DiskElementId,
      q.FileName /* prior filename ?? */ as Parent,
      q.TopParent /*CONNECT_BY_ROOT FileName as TopParent ??? */ as TopParent,
      Files.FileName
    FROM Files INNER JOIN q ON files.parentdiskelementid = q.DiskElementId
)
SELECT DiskElementId, Parent,TopParent,FileName FROM q ORDER BY DiskElementId;
```

Both queries return the same data

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be a huge help here. You can see [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some ideas on how to post this stuff.

Comment: Have you tried the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54258

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? "Check my code" is a bit broad. With regards to the two choices, the connect-by wins hands down for me: you are using the tool as Oracle intended. The recursive query is too cumbersome and complex to follow, and it doesn't perform as well.